# Flutter. Request for solve the problem of correct output of numbers and symbols input in real time

Tags: flutter

In the process of creating a general calculator, I want to receive the button input value in
the statement, display it on the screen in real time, and have the correct value displayed in
the result when the "=" button is clicked. However, when I use the numberformatter to add a
three-digit comma to the real-time input value, an invalid double error occurs. When I
randomly input 99*9 into double.parse(statementConvert) and then try to add one more number,
an invalid double error occurs. I understand that the error occurs because a sign other than
a number is entered, but I don't know how to solve this problem. I am sharing the code for
the problem below, so please help me solve it.

```
import 'package:math_expressions/math_expressions.dart';
import 'package:simple_calculator/numberformatter.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

if (text == "+" || text == "-" || text == "*" || text == "/" || text == ".") {
  statement = statement + text;
} else if (statement.endsWith("+") || statement.endsWith("-") || statement.endsWith("*")
  || statement.endsWith("/")) {
  statement = statement + text;
} else if (text == "00" || text == "0" || text == "1" || text == "2" || text == "3" ||
  text == "4" || text == "5" || text == "6" || text == "7" || text == "8" || text == "9") {
  statement = statement + text;
  var statementConvert = statement.replaceAll(',', '');
  statement = numberFormatter2(double.parse(statementConvert)); // ex) 9,999*9 A double invalid error occurs when entering the following number.
}

calculate() {
  try {
   var exp = Parser().parse(statement);
   var evaluation = exp.evaluate(EvaluationType.REAL, ContextModel());
   return evaluation.toString();
  } catch (e) {
   showToast("Please check the formula.");
   return;
  }
}

String numberFormatter2(double number) {
 final numberFormatter = NumberFormat('#,##0.########');
 return numberFormatter.format(number);
}
```

Looking at the unresolved code above, I tried many conditional statements, but I couldn't
completely solve it. I am attaching an image to help you understand. Please help.